# Rails: What does calling ActionController::Parameters#permit() achieve when not using the object returned by it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, discourse, actionpack

[I understand](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) that calling `params.permit(:foo)` creates a new `ActionController::Parameters` instance with `:foo` whitelisted so that you can instantiate a model with it. But why does the following code in the Discourse CMS call it without using its return value?

`discourse/app/controllers/drafts_controller.rb`: [Github](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/controllers/drafts_controller.rb#L10)

```
class DraftsController < ApplicationController
  # [...]

  def index
    # [...]
    params.permit(:offset)
    params.permit(:limit)

    # [...]

    opts = {
        # [...]
        offset: params[:offset],
        limit: params[:limit]
    }

    stream = Draft.stream(opts)
```

Comment: Depends on your `action_on_unpermitted_parameters` configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This does look confusing, I agree.

Judging from the implementation of [`#permit`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f33d52c95217212cbacc8d5e44b5a8e3cdc6f5b3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L543-L558) and the documentation of [`ActionController::Params`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html), this can behave differently depending on the config `action_on_unpermitted_parameters`, which accepts `:log` and `:raise` as values and is `nil` by default.

**When `action_on_unpermitted_parameters = nil`:**

Calling `params.permit(:foo)` will return a new `ActionController::Parameters` instance marked as permitted with just that key.

If you're not using the return value, this call makes little sense as there's no side effect. The receiver is not mutated.

**When `action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :log`:**

This behaves the same as above, but has the side effect of logging all not permitted keys:

```
irb> ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :log
=> :log
irb> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(username: 'john', offset: 5, bogus: 'foo')
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"john", "offset"=>5, "bogus"=>"foo"} permitted: false>
irb> params.require(:username)
=> "john"
irb> params.permit(:offset)
Unpermitted parameters: :username, :bogus
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"offset"=>5} permitted: true>
irb> params.permit(:limit)
Unpermitted parameters: :username, :offset, :bogus
=> <ActionController::Parameters {} permitted: true>
```

As you can see, for each `permit` call, you'd get different logs. Thus, this would only make sense if the code in that controller would include all permitted (and required) parameters:

```
irb> params.permit(:username, :offset, :limit)
Unpermitted parameter: :bogus
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"john", "offset"=>5} permitted: true>
```

**When `action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise`:**

The effect here is that it raises when the params contain keys that are not allowed. Similar to `:log`, this also only would make sense when all permitted (and required) keys are specified:

```
irb> ActionController::Parameters.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
=> :raise
irb> params = ActionController::Parameters.new(username: 'john', offset: 5, bogus: 'foo')
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"john", "offset"=>5, "bogus"=>"foo"} permitted: false>
irb> params.require(:username)
=> "john"
irb> params.permit(:offset)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):19
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameters: :username, :bogus)
irb> params.permit(:limit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):20
        1: from (irb):20:in `rescue in irb_binding'
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameters: :username, :offset, :bogus)
```

Contrast that to including all keys:

```
irb> params.permit(:username, :offset, :limit)
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):21
        1: from (irb):21:in `rescue in irb_binding'
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter: :bogus)
```

---

Having said that, I couldn't find any occurrence of `action_on_unpermitted_parameters` in Discourse's codebase. Thus, the value is `nil` and therefore I conclude that `#permit` in that controller action has no effect in terms of functionality.

It could be there as a **convention serving as documentation** where first all required parameters are listed and then all optional ones.

Digging deeper, these `#permit` calls were introduced in this [commit](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/commit/661ddbb15821a6cbb6b0fd30b31d76ed728b60c0) when it was still a separate gem called *strong_parameters*. The behavior of `#permit` in that gem was the same as today. This makes me think that the author of that commit misunderstood the API of *strong_parameters*.